# 'ps' without kernel threads

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

I'm looking for some solutions to use `ps auxf` command to show all processes without kernel threads, or maybe anyone know any else program to filter that kernel process?

What I've tried and found:

```
ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect
```

OK, but the processes are not arranged like in the usual 'ps aux':

```
ps axl | awk '$7 != 0 && $10 !~ "Z"'
```

much more chaos in result

```
ps auxf | grep -v ]$
```

In my opinion, it's a stupid solution to cut out after this sign. There are normal processes with ' [ ] '

It would be great if there was a switch like: `-k -- show kernel threads` :) and any other option would only show the system processes beginning with Init. Then, using `ps aux` or `ps auxf` would be more convenient.

Someone? something? knows any better solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the `u` in `ps aux` which defines the output columns. You can use:

```
ps u --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect
```

Comment: According to `man ps` :: Commands options such as `ps -aux` are not recommended as it is a confusion of two different standards.  According to the POSIX and UNIX standards, the above command asks to display all processes with a TTY (generally the commands users are running) plus all processes owned by a user named "x".  If that user doesn't exist, then ps will assume you really meant `ps aux`.

Comment: Sure, but how is that related to my answer?

Comment: What I meant to say is that I believe you have a typo : `ps aux` vs `ps -aux`

Comment: I see. Yeah, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ps -ef | awk '$3!= "2" {print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`--deselect/-N` negates all conditions, not only those `--ppid 2` and `--pid 2`.
There is a better way:

```bash
LIBPROC_HIDE_KERNEL=1 ps faxu # <-- or your beloved keys ...
```